# Open link in safari after selected particular index in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 array object which contains name and file name. Just like this:

```
name={"PRESENTATION FILE", "MEETING DOCUMENT", "REPORT"}
file={"item1.ppt", "item2.pdf", "item3.pdf"}
```

I am using this code in my TableViewCell to show the document

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   Document * documentObject;
   documentObject = [_all_documentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.textLabel.text = documentObject.name;

   NSString *doc_link =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://localhost/database/%@",documentObject.file];
   NSURL *doc_url=[NSURL URLWithString:doc_link];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:doc_url];

   return cell;
}
```

When I do this the the first link appears immediately after I open the tableview. What I need to do so I will be able to open link with the same index with the list I choose? Sorry for bad english and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     Document * documentObject;
    documentObject = [_all_documentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSString *doc_link =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://localhost/database/%@",documentObject.file];
    NSURL *doc_url=[NSURL URLWithString:doc_link];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:doc_url];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *doc_link =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://localhost/database/%@",documentObject.file];
NSURL *doc_url=[NSURL URLWithString:doc_link];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:doc_url];
```

`CellForRow` method is for the Preparation of the cells, how they will Look, configuring the elements of the cell and linking them to methods etc.

Implement these lines of code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` tableView Delegate Method.

Get the index from `indexPath.row`, use the index to get proper object from the Array and then use the lines of code to open the URL.

Comment: I am really new in Xcode and objective c. I don't understand how to do what you instructed. Can you please show me the code to do that? @croyneaus4u

Comment: Sorry dude. I don't have a system handy. You can find the code in Apple docs, read through please. How to implement functionality of a cell in table view. Cheers.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to look around for an answer. Thanks @croyneaus4u